# How to join two collections in Firebase using expressjs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I am writing Rest API's using node-express JS with Firebase database. In Firebase , I have two collections like:

```
    Bin (binName, binLocaton, hardwareId)

    BinsInformation (date, payloadFields { hardwareId, levle })
```

How could I join these two collections based on field `hardwareId`?

```
I would like to join to collections like two tables in MySQL. 

Ex. "SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id "
 Like the above MySQL query i would like join my two collections "Bin" and "BinInformation".
```

If i join with single doc with particular id  its giving correct output . but when iam trying to join all the docs in the two collections 
    with a separate  query its giving "Asynchronous Error".

here is my collections:

Bins:

```
[
    {
        AreaID: "ZYwQHIrZPEDd359e6WRf"
        Capacity: "123"
        Latitude: "17.658745"
        LocationName: "testing"
        Longitude: "78.9874545"
        hardwareid: "4321"
    },
    {
        AreaID: "ZYwQHIrZPEDd359e6WRf"
        Capacity: "123"
        Latitude: "17.658745"
        LocationName: "testing"
        Longitude: "78.9874545"
        hardwareid: "5432"
    }
]
```

BinInformation:

```
[
    {
        date: September 24, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM UTC+5:30,
        payload_fields: { 
            hardwareid: "4321"
            level : 60
        }
    },
    {
        date: September 24, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM UTC+5:30,
        payload_fields: { 
            hardwareid: "5432"
            level : 23
        }
    }
]
```

Here i need to get all Bins with corresponding BinInformation . my code goes like this

```
app.get('/twoColectionJoin', asyncHandler( async (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('await');
    try {

        let allDocs = [];

        const snapshot = await db.collection('Bins').get();

        let i = 0;
         snapshot.forEach( async (doc) => {
            let dummyDoc = doc.data();
            const details = await getBinDet(dummyDoc.hardwareid);
            dummyDoc.id = doc.id;  
            dummyDoc.det = details;              
            allDocs.push(dummyDoc);
            i++;
            console.log(allDocs);
        });

            res.status(200).send(allDocs);


    }
    catch(e){

        next(e);
    }
}) );


async function getBinDet(hardwareid){
    let dummyDoc = {};
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        try{

            setTimeout(function(){ 
             db.collection('BinsInformation')
             .where('payload_fields.hardwareid', '==', hardwareid)
             .limit(1).get()
                .then(snap => {                 
                    snap.forEach(element => {

                        //return element.data();
                        dummyDoc = element.data();

                    });   

                    resolve(dummyDoc);
                })
                .catch(err2 => {

                        reject(err2);
                });
            }, 300);

        }catch(err){

            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Expected Output :

```
[
    {
        AreaID: "ZYwQHIrZPEDd359e6WRf"
        Capacity: "123"
        Latitude: "17.658745"
        LocationName: "testing"
        Longitude: "78.9874545"
        hardwareid: "4321",
        det: {
            date: September 24, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM UTC+5:30,
            payload_fields : { 
                hardwareid: "4321"
                level : 60
            }
        }
    },
    {
        AreaID: "ZYwQHIrZPEDd359e6WRf"
        Capacity: "123"
        Latitude: "17.658745"
        LocationName: "testing"
        Longitude: "78.9874545"
        hardwareid: "5432",
        det: {
            date: September 24, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM UTC+5:30,
            payload_fields: { 
                hardwareid: "5432"
                level : 23
            }
        }
    }
]
```

But the resulting output is : []

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting SQL queries to Firebase query isn't 1:1. And if you're trying to perform typical SQL queries on Firebase, then Firebase is the wrong database (NoSQL) is not for you.

Using the data structure you posted above, a complete example would be like:

```
const express = require("express");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

const app = express();

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://example.firebaseio.com"
});

const db = admin.firestore();

async function joinsCollectionsHandler(req, res) {
  const binsRef = await db.collection("bins").get();
  const binData = binsRef.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

  const binsInfoRef = await db.collection("bin-information").get();
  const binInfoData = binsInfoRef.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

  const data = binData.map(bin => {
    const { hardwareId } = bin;
    const det = binInfoData.filter(
      doc => doc.payloadFields.hardwareId === hardwareId
    );
    return { ...bin, det };
  });
  res.json(data);
}

app.get("/twoColectionJoin", joinsCollectionsHandler);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Started on 3000"));
```

The end result is:

```
[
    {
        "latitude": "17.658745",
        "locationName": "testing",
        "longitude": "78.9874545",
        "areaId": "ZYwQHIrZPEDd359e6WRf",
        "hardwareId": "5432",
        "capacity": "123",
        "det": [
            {
                "date": "2018-09-23T18:30:00.000Z",
                "payloadFields": {
                    "level": 23,
                    "hardwareId": "5432"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "capacity": "123",
        "areaId": "ZYwQHIrZPEDd359e6WRf",
        "latitude": "17.658745",
        "hardwareId": "4321",
        "locationName": "testing",
        "det": [
            {
                "date": "2018-09-23T18:30:00.000Z",
                "payloadFields": {
                    "level": 60,
                    "hardwareId": "4321"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tested this locally and works fine. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: hi Mateo , when iam joining single doc with particular id its working fine but when iam trying to join all the docs in two collection getting Async Error . added some content to question to get clarify my issue . please check it once

Comment: Thanks for posting your collection structure, I'll see what I can come up after work today if no one has answered yet.

Comment: Are you using Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore?

Comment: It is Cloud firestore only

Comment: @SathishGorinta see my updated answer. Let me know if you have any questions.